# No known expression from value to value&... Why?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have tried writing a function which takes a `ColXpr` value as input:

```
typedef Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Signal2D;

void Threshold(Signal2D::ColXpr& params)
{
  params = (params >= 0.0f).template cast<float>();
}
```

When I try to call this function I do something like this:

```
Signal2D arr;
// fill it with stuff
Threshold(arr.col(0));
```

Then I get this compiler error:

```
src/core/Neuron.h:91:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1> >::ColXpr {aka Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>}’ to ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1> >::ColXpr& {aka Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>&}’
make: *** [src/training/Fibonacci.o] Error 1
```

Without reposting the entire series of code that leads to this, could someone explain what it *means* when the compiler says `no known conversion for argument from Value to Value&`? Why can't it get a reference in this instance? Note that I've seen a similar problem related to the `this` pointer which I've posted here:

[error: no match for 'operator<<' using boost::serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440210/error-no-match-for-operator-using-boostserialisation?noredirect=1#comment35931051_23440210)

Could this be some peculiarity of GCC 4.9.0 or am I doing something wrong here? Please let me know if you need to see a self-contained example, it will take a while to cobble together and I thought there might be enough info here to point out an obvious error on my part.

Comment: Let me guess - `arr.col()` returns a `Signal2D` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb no, `Eigen::Array::col()` returns `Eigen::ColXpr`. There was a mistake in my example code (fixed), see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a58c77695de3b33405f01f2fdf3dc389d

Comment: Is that the same as `Signal2D::ColXpr`? (I see you just edited what `Threshold` takes)

Comment: @MattMcNabb My understanding is yes. And judging from the error they *are* the same type, but please correct me if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, a temporary object cannot bind to a non-const reference.

I'm assuming that `arr.col(0)` returns an object by value. The returned value is a temporary object. This means it cannot match a parameter of type `T &`.

One solution:

```
auto temp = arr.col(0);
Threshold(temp);
```

I wonder if you intended for `arr.col()` to return a reference?

Comment: Yes, i did... Looks like I'll need to build on my Eigen undersatnding here a bit..

Answer (score 3):

To complete previous answers, you're probably looking for the `Ref<>` class which will allow you to write a function that accept both columns of a matrix and vectors without templates nor copies:

```
void threshold(Ref<ArrayXf> params) {
    params = (params >= 0 ).cast<float>();
}
ArrayXf  a;
ArrayXXf A;
/* ... */
threshold(a);
threshold(A.col(j));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above:

Eigen return expressions are temporaries.  E.g. `ColXpr` is just a small copyable object that gives you access to the array data.  It is returned by value,  `ColXpr col(...)`. You can capture the ColXpr temporary with const reference but not otherwise.

However you can write:

```
void Threshold(Matrix::ColXpr col);
```

Generally, it is frowned upon to modify Eigen expression in functions.
The preferred way is to write unary/binary functors/lambdas eg:

```
array.col(i) = array.col(i).unaryExpr(
  [](const float &value) {
    return float(value >= 0); 
  }
);
```

Btw, if you intend to write generic Eigen functions, use `Eigen::EigenBase<B>` as arguments to capture any eigen expression, see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Boost serialization requires non-temporary reference as well, even the operand is being written to an archive.