# How to write a wrapper for doubles to use with boost serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, wrapper

The boost serialization library fails to handle special values for doubles  correctly when using text archives. That is, trying to deserialize NaN, +inf or -inf will lead to an error (see e.g. [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696663/boost-serialization-1-5-5-crash-when-meets-nan-and-inf)).

Therefore I want to write a wrapper class/method, similar to make_array or make_binary_object (see [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html)) to handle those values. I want to use it like this:

```
class MyClass {

public:
    double value;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int){
        ar & Double_wrapper(value);
    }
};
```

However, I fail to understand how wrapper classes work internally. Especially I do not understand, how they manage to preserve the connection to the original variable (in this case value) when deserializing.

I tried to write the wrapper like this:

```
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

class Double_wrapper {

private:
    enum double_type {DT_NONE, DT_NAN, DT_INF, DT_NINF};

    double& value;

public:
    Double_wrapper(double& val):value(val){}
    Double_wrapper(Double_wrapper const& rhs):value(rhs.value) {}

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) const {
        double_type flag = DT_NONE;
        double val = value;

        if (!std::isfinite(val)) {
            if (std::isnan(val))    {
                flag = DT_NAN;
            } else if (val > 0) {
                flag = DT_INF;
            } else {
                flag = DT_NINF;
            }
            val = 0;
        }

        ar & val;
        ar & flag;
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) const {
        double_type flag;

        ar & value;
        ar & flag;

        switch (flag) {
            case DT_NONE:   break;
            case DT_NAN:    value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); break;
            case DT_INF:    value = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); break;
            case DT_NINF:   value = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }
    }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};

BOOST_CLASS_IS_WRAPPER(Double_wrapper)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Double_wrapper, boost::serialization::track_never)
```

However, this is more the result of a trial and error process, than of understanding how wrappers work. From [this part of the doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#wrappers) I concluded, that I would need to declare the class as a wrapper. But it doesn't seem to work.

When I try to use above code with this MWE

```
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

#include <boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Double_wrapper {

private:
    enum double_type {DT_NONE, DT_NAN, DT_INF, DT_NINF};

    double& value;

public:
    Double_wrapper(double& val):value(val){}
    Double_wrapper(Double_wrapper const& rhs):value(rhs.value) {}

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) const {
        double_type flag = DT_NONE;
        double val = value;

        if (!std::isfinite(val)) {
            if (std::isnan(val))    {
                flag = DT_NAN;
            } else if (val > 0) {
                flag = DT_INF;
            } else {
                flag = DT_NINF;
            }
            val = 0;
        }

        ar & val;
        ar & flag;
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) const {
        double_type flag;

        ar & value;
        ar & flag;

        switch (flag) {
            case DT_NONE:   break;
            case DT_NAN:    value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); break;
            case DT_INF:    value = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); break;
            case DT_NINF:   value = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }
    }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};

BOOST_CLASS_IS_WRAPPER(Double_wrapper)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Double_wrapper, boost::serialization::track_never)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class MyClass {

public:
    double value;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int){
        ar & Double_wrapper(value);
    }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {

    MyClass tmp;
    tmp.value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();

    std::cout << "value=" << tmp.value << std::endl;

    std::string filename(boost::archive::tmpdir());
    filename += "/tmp.txt";

    //Output
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::out);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(ofs);
    oar << tmp;

    ofs.close();

    //Input
    MyClass newtmp;
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ifs);
    iar >> newtmp;

    std::cout << "value=" << newtmp.value << std::endl;

}
```

it fails. It gives me the error

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   ‘Double_wrapper&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Double_wrapper’

for the line

> ar & Double_wrapper(value);

So I am not sure what to do. It seems that using references doesn't work. Will pointers do the trick? Does this work at all?

Any help and/or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

I am using boost version 1.58 on Ubuntu.

---

**Update**
The code seems to work with vc++ as mentioned in the comments. However, interpreting the statements made in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440210/error-no-match-for-operator-using-boostserialisation) seems to suggest, that it in fact does not, since

> The reason MSVC might have accepted it, nonetheless, could be because MSVC has an (evil) non-standard extension that extends lifetimes of temporaries, when bound to a non-const reference.

If I understand this correctly, it should not work anymore when shutting down the program after saving and trying to deserialize in a new instance.

---

**Update**
As suggested by John Zwinck, there may be a workaround by replacing the call

```
ar & Double_wrapper(value);
```

by

```
Double_wrapper wrapper(value);
ar & wrapper;
```

However, this does not seem to be the intended behavior of a wrapper object for boost serialization. Moreover, it is unclear (to me) whether this solution is stable (I need it to run with every c++ compiler).

It seems to work on my computer with g++ 5.4.0 and clang++ 3.8.0. Furthermore it works with [vc++ on Rextester](http://rextester.com/SIJWN38395) (boost 1.6).

It produces an archive exception when run with [g++ 4.9.3 on rextester](http://rextester.com/HSDBW66217) (boost 1.54). I wasn't able to test it with clang 3.7 on rextester or g++ 6.1.0 on coliru yet due to (presumably unrelated) linker errors.

Comment: Why are you using a const_cast in Double_wrapper::load(...). Your value is not constant so from what I understand this would be undefined behavior, the compiler can't deal with it. static_cast works. [only const_cast may be used to cast away (remove) constness](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)

Comment: You're right, thank you. The value inside of Double_wrapper was const before and I did not remove the const_cast. I will remove the const_cast's in the question.

However, either way the behavior does not change.

Comment: You are still getting the same error with the above code? It compiles and runs fine, (with a oar.close( ) after output), on Microsoft's V140.

Comment: Yes, I do. That is interesting. So it may be a compiler-dependent problem? Thank you very much so far, I will check it again tomorrow (11.30 pm here) and post the compiler flags I use.

In some thread I read, that there may be a problem with ld_library_path, but I ignored this until now. Maybe I will have a look at this.

Comment: Just to be sure we were not crossing up, I copied exactly what you have now and it compiled  without an error or warning, and ran fine, with the ofs.close( );

Comment: Just because, I tried it on g++ [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50e7aadcf896fe64). I'll take a look at errors and see if I can ferret this out.

Comment: My compiler flags seem to have no influence on the result (running without any flags produces the same error).

I could confirm, using [Rextester](http://rextester.com/live/YWDTIV21879), that it runs fine with vc++. With rextester's [gcc](http://rextester.com/live/TJYU89127) and clang I get the error message

error: no match for ‘operator&’ (operand types are boost::archive::text_oarchive’ and ‘Double_wrapper’)
         ar & Double_wrapper(value);

But this seems to be the same problem as before.

(I added the ofs.close and included iostream in the MWE above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of this:

```
    ar & Double_wrapper(value);
```

You should do this:

```
    Double_wrapper wrapper(value);
    ar & wrapper;
```

Reason being that your error message complains about the fact that you're using an rvalue where it wants an lvalue.

Comment: Thank you! This looks easy enough to be sufficient for what I am planning to do. I was aware of the issue, but thought I couldn't change it without splitting the serialization in two parts.

However, I am still unsure about two points:

1. Why does it work as I expected for e.g. make_array or make_binary_object? What is the difference?

2. Why does this work at all? Shouldn't the deserialization create a completely new object? How does it preserve the reference then? Is there any specification about this?

Comment: Also note that the macro BOOST_CLASS_IS_WRAPPER is not needed then. I think this macro should be the key to using the wrapper as I want to, but I don't understand how it works (and why it doesn't).

Comment: Hi John, I tried that yesterday on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5efa428e8d12c537). But it made boost blowup with gcc. It worked with the MS compiler. Cero, did it work with your compiler?

Comment: I was not buying it. Double_wrapper is constructed on the stack and is not an rvalue from what I understand. So to be sure I added ~Double_wrapper( ) to the class and set a break point. Is it possible that gcc is getting confused here?

Comment: Yes, this works with my compiler. Not with gcc and clang on rextester though.
I use g++ 5.4.0.